# How do I find a model for Refinery's built-in users in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, refinerycms, refinery

I am using Refinery and want to make edits to a RefineryUser.  In the schema file I see the following:

```
  create_table "refinery_authentication_devise_users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "username",               null: false
    t.string   "email",                  null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "slug"
    t.string   "full_name"
  end
```

But I cannot find a model.  How do I find the model so I can add callbacks, validations, and other code to RefineryUsers.  I may also add ActiveAdmin and make the refinery user an activeadmin user.

Answer (score 0):

User models stands in https://github.com/refinery/refinerycms-authentication-devise if you use this extension. If you would like to use ActiveAdmin, you will probably have to hack it: https://github.com/refinery/refinerycms-authentication-devise/issues/16